# Parallel For calling other Methods

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

new to Parallel processing. I'm having the issue where I have a parallel for loop calling a method to get data. However, it seems that the data is getting mixed up upon the return. It could be the code but everything I've tried in debugging looks okay.

Parallel For:

```cs
Parallel.For(0, LeagueParticipantsList.Count, n => {
  if (!LeagueParticipantsList[n].ToString().Equals("")) {
//Other non important code here
     History = Scanning.GoogleConnection.LogCheck(LeagueParticipantsList[n].ToString());
//Other non important code here
});
```

Method it's calling:

```cs
public static List<ClanHistoryData> LogCheck(String clashID) {
  
List<ClanHistoryData> Results = new List<ClanHistoryData>();

  var clansMap = json["log"];

  DateTime curDTp90 = DateTime.Now;
  curDTp90 = curDTp90.AddDays(-90);

  foreach (var item in clansMap) {
    if (item["type"].ToString().Equals("SEEN")) {
      string tempDate = item["date"].ToString();
      DateTime dateStuff = DateTime.Parse(tempDate);
      if (DateTime.Compare(dateStuff, curDTp90) > 0) {
        Results.Add(new ClanHistoryData(
                     item["tag"].ToString(),
                     dateStuff
                    ));
       }
    } else if {//Same thing here but item["type"].ToString().Equals("STAY")}

  if (Results.Count == 0) Results.Add(new ClanHistoryData("0", DateTime.Now));

  } catch (Exception e) {
    Results.Add(new ClanHistoryData("-1", DateTime.Now));
  }

  return Results;
}
```

Not sure what's going wrong, if it has to do with calling the method from a parallel loop. If the Data is getting messed up in the List. I was thinking since the method is running on different threads there wouldn't be an issue with that.

I get the same number of values but each run they are on a different Identifier, never the same (the identifies don't change)

Comment: `clashID` param does not seem to be used. Is that intended or due to shortening the snippet?

Comment: Yes, that is used as last of an api call to get the Json that the “LogCheck” is reading from

Answer (score 0):

When doing any parallel processing, things become **much** easier if data is immutable and methods are pure.

Your LogCheck method uses `DateTime.Now`, so it is not pure. Parallel.For is free to run the iterations in any order i wants to, so it is not unexpected that the results will be semi-random.

To fix this you should probably take the dataTime as a parameter to the method, and capture this outside the parallel.for, so it has the same value for all calls. Then the results will probably be identical since you do not seem to use the `clashID` parameter.

Comment: The date time being off in seconds has no effect. As i only care about the date and not the time. I’m just checking to see if the data I’m pulling in is within the past 90 days. The clashiD parameter is used above that part in an API request I just didn’t include that part.

Comment: Then either the used data is changed between calls due to some external factor, or the method itself mutate the data. I cannot spot any mutating going on, but I might have missed it. But either case will cause issues since the result depend on factors that are difficult to reason about, especially when running in parallel. And the solution is the same, extract any non-pure methods to be outside the method and ensure it only mutates local variables.